# Query regarding call by value and call by reference in Python

Tags: python, memory, reference

I am quite confused, which case is correct, first case or second case or both the cases are correct in Python?

- Why in first case the list `x` remain unchanged?
- why in second case the list `x` also got modified?

Case 1:

```py
x = [0, 1, 2]

def cleanIt(y):
    y = []
    return y

print(cleanIt(x)) #[]
print(x)          #[0, 1, 2]
```

Case 2:

```
x = [0, 1, 2]
    
def appendOne(z):
    z.append(4)
    return z

print(appendOne(x)) #[0, 1, 2, 4]
print(x)            #[0, 1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `id()` to give you a clear idea of the references. *`id()` returns the memory address of the argument passed to it.*

#### Case-1

```
x = [0, 1, 2]
    
print(id(x))  
def cleanIt(y):
    print(id(y))
    y = []
    print(id(y))
    return y

print(cleanIt(x))
print(x)
```

```
Output:

139677941202304
139677941202304
139677940574528
[]
[0, 1, 2]
```

- You pass the reference of `x` to `cleanIt`.
- `y = []` - Creates a new list altogether. This has nothing to do with `x`. *See the references above.*
- `return y` - You return the newly created list i.e, `y = []`
- Since `x` is unchanged, it will retain its initial values.

#### Case-2

```
x = [0, 1, 2]
print(id(x))

def appendOne(z):
    print(id(z))
    z.append(4)
    print(id(z))
    return z

print(appendOne(x))
print(x)
```

```
Output

139677940574912
139677940574912
139677940574912
[0, 1, 2, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 4]
```

- You pass the reference of `x` to `appendOne()`. `x` and `z` point to the same list.
- `z.append(4)` - Appends a 4 to list referenced by `z`.
- Since `z` and `x` refer to the same list, changes made  in `z` reflects in `x` too. *See the references above.*

**In Python values are sent to functions by means of object reference.**

*Please read [this](https://medium.com/@lokeshsharma596/is-python-call-by-value-or-call-by-reference-2dd7db74dbd0) to know more about this concept.*

**Edit:**

*If I want to have x unchanged while z should be [0,1,2,4], then how should I modify the python code?*

This is how you can do.

```
x = [0, 1, 2]
print(id(x))

def appendOne(z):
    print(id(z))
    # Creates a new list with contents of x.
    z = list(z)
    z.append(4)
    print(id(z))
    return z

print(appendOne(x))
print(x)
```

```
Output

140368975642112
140368975642112
140368975011392
[0, 1, 2, 4]
[0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: If I want to have x unchanged while z should be [0,1,2,4], then how should I modify the python code?

Answer (score 1):

Python behaves like **pass-by-object-reference**. Therefore what you really pass into the functions are actually references to the objects you give. In the first example, you pass a reference that points to the memory address in which x is present. However when you do the assignment operation `y = []`, you simply change the memory address your reference points to. You do not change the content of x. In the second example, you call the method `append()`. In that case, you call this method for the object that is present in the memory address pointed to by your reference. 
These may come confusing at the beginning, but you should remember that assigning your variable directly to something else doesn't actually change your variable, it changes where your reference points to. However using a method, modifying your variable updates it.

Comment: If I want to have x unchanged while z should be [0,1,2,4], then how should I modify the python code?

Comment: You should create a brand new list within your function using the list constructor. ```z = list(z)``` should create new list. Then call ```z.append(4)``` and ```return z```.